# How to get friends name in fql

Tags: iphone, facebook-fql

I am executing this query in FQL [@"SELECT likes,message,actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = %lld  limit 50", _session.uid]. It is giving result well but I want to fetch my friends name also. I don't want to execute query within loop to fetch friends name from their profile. If it is possible in multiquery then which type of query I will have to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code:

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %lld)", session.uid];
```

Hope it can give you a hint.

Comment: Is it give friends name related with post or message from stream table. I am fetching message from stream table and I want to fetch name of friend. will it work ?

Comment: I used it only for get the list of my friends after I logined.Maybe you can have a try.